# Why is BlocBuilder not rebuilding?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am building a small notes app to learn Bloc, but I am running into an issue where `BlocBuilder` only rebuilds the first time the state becomes `NoteOpen` (`NoteInitial` -> `NoteOpen`). It does not refresh on subsequent `NoteOpen` states even though they are different.

```dart
// The BlocBuilder that is not rebuilding... 
class Editor extends StatelessWidget {
  const Editor({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<NoteBloc, NoteState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => true,
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is NoteInitial) {
            return _noNoteSelected(state);
          }
          return _displayNote(state as NoteOpen);
        }
    );
  }

  // rest of code omitted
```

The bloc:

```dart
class NoteBloc extends Bloc<NoteEvent, NoteState> {
  NoteBloc() : super(NoteInitial()) {
    on<NoteSelected>(_onNoteSelected);
  }

  Future<void> _onNoteSelected(
    NoteSelected event,
    Emitter<NoteState> emit,
  ) async {
    await NotesFilesLoader().load(event.fileSummary).then((note) => emit(NoteOpen(note: note)));
  }
}
```

The states:

```dart
sealed class NoteState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class NoteInitial extends NoteState {}

class NoteOpen extends NoteState {
  final Note note;

  NoteOpen({required this.note});


  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'NoteOpen{note: ${note.title}}';
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [note.title]; //All I want for now is use the note title for the equals check
}
```

This is the parent widget:

```dart
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
          thumbVisibility: MaterialStateProperty.all<bool>(true),
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => NoteBloc(), //bloc is created here
            child: VerticalSplitView(
              ratio: 0.25,
              left: const FilesExplorerPage(),
              right: Editor(), // the offending BlocBuilder is here
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget that fires the event:

```dart
class _FilesExplorerState extends State<FilesExplorer> {
  int? _selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<FileExplorerCubit, List<FileSummary>>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: state.isEmpty ? _loadingFiles(context) : _buildFileList(state),
      );
    });
  }

  ListView _buildFileList(List<FileSummary> fileSummaries) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 3),
      itemCount: fileSummaries.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            context.read<NoteBloc>().add(NoteSelected(fileSummary: fileSummaries[index])); // event gets fired here
            setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
          },
          child: _selectedIndex == index
              ? _selectedContainer(Text(fileSummaries[index].title))
              : Text(fileSummaries[index].title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // omitted code
```

Finally, I have a global observer to debug the issue:

```dart
class DebugObserver extends BlocObserver {

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);

    print("Equals? ${change.currentState == change.nextState}");
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $change');
  }
}
```

The output:

```dart
flutter: NoteBloc Change { currentState: NoteOpen{note: Welcome Note}, nextState: NoteOpen{note: How To Use The App} }
flutter: Equals? false
flutter: NoteBloc Change { currentState: NoteOpen{note: How To Use The App}, nextState: NoteOpen{note: Welcome Note} }
flutter: Equals? false
flutter: NoteBloc Change { currentState: NoteOpen{note: Welcome Note}, nextState: NoteOpen{note: How To Use The App} }
flutter: Equals? false
flutter: NoteBloc Change { currentState: NoteOpen{note: How To Use The App}, nextState: NoteOpen{note: Welcome Note} }
```

Can you tell me why `BlocBuilder` is rebuilding only on the first `NoteOpen` state?

**Update**
`FileExplorerCubit` is used here:

```dart
class FilesExplorerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FilesExplorerPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<FileExplorerCubit>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => FileExplorerCubit(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const FilesExplorer(),
    );
  }
}

class FilesExplorer extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilesExplorer({super.key});

  @override
  State<FilesExplorer> createState() => _FilesExplorerState();
}

class _FilesExplorerState extends State<FilesExplorer> {
  int? _selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<FileExplorerCubit, List<FileSummary>>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: state.isEmpty ? _loadingFiles(context) : _buildFileList(state),
      );
    });
  }

  ListView _buildFileList(List<FileSummary> fileSummaries) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 3),
      itemCount: fileSummaries.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            context.read<NoteBloc>().add(NoteSelected(fileSummary: fileSummaries[index]));
            setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
          },
          child: _selectedIndex == index
              ? _selectedContainer(Text(fileSummaries[index].title))
              : Text(fileSummaries[index].title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // omitted code
}
```

Comment: Can you try `then` after `await` section.   >>  `Summary).then((note`

Comment: It's there: `await NotesFilesLoader().load(event.fileSummary).then((note) => emit(NoteOpen(note: note)));`

Comment: just to be sure you didn't create by accident another NoteBloc somewhere else? I see you have FileExplorerCubit but don't see it created anywhere so to be sure how/where are you intializing your other blocs

Comment: I was referring not mixing `await` and `then` 

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I've tried it out - it did not work.

Comment: @EdwynZN I updated the question to include where the cubit is created/used

Comment: The fact the observer detect the changes should be enough proof that it's working and is something related to the widget, do you can you test with a breakpoint in the builder method and check for state changes?

Comment: The builder method does not get called again after the first NoteOpen

Answer (score 0):

usually the problem is that the bloc builder does not make changes because the emitted state is still the same.
in this case the currentState and nextState are still the same, namely NoteOpen
to make changes, a state change trigger is needed first, add emit NoteLoading to the _onNoteSelected function, so that the state becomes NoteLoading, then finally the state changes back to NoteOpen.

```dart
Future<void> _onNoteSelected(
 NoteSelected event,
 Emitter<NoteState> emit,
) async {
 emit(NoteLoading); // add this state first
 await NotesFilesLoader().load(event.fileSummary).
 then((note) => emit(NoteOpen(note: note)));
 }
```